# Save button not saving everything

Tags: vb.net

I have a save button in my project and it is supposed to save the contents of my 2 listboxes into a textfile, but it isn't saving everything. Instead, it deletes the last 5 lines of one of the listboxs. What have I done wrong with my code?

```
Dim loops As Integer 'Declare variable
    Dim savefile As New SaveFileDialog
    savefile.FileName = ""
    savefile.Filter = "textfiles(*.txt)|*.txt|file(*)|*|All files('.')|'.')"
    savefile.Title = "save"
    savefile.ShowDialog()
    Try
        Dim write As New System.IO.StreamWriter(savefile.FileName) 'Write and save a new file
        For loops = 1 To itemcount - 1 'loop until no lines are left in listbox
            write.WriteLine(firstname(loops)) 'Write out firstname
            write.WriteLine(lastname(loops)) 'Write out lastname
            write.WriteLine(gender(loops)) 'Write out gender 
            write.WriteLine(applicationdate(loops)) 'Write out date of regestration
            write.WriteLine(address(loops)) 'Write out address
        Next
        write.Close() 'Close file
        MsgBox("File Saved") 'Display message box
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
```

Comment: Where do you get the value of itemcount?

Comment: is an exception being thrown somewhere?  Your code silently ignores any exceptions.

Comment: Yes, as @orzechowskid said, remove that empty catch and see if exception for Index out of Range appears

Comment: When I get rid of the catch, no error comes up, but it does make the program hang, so it definitely causes something to happen.

Comment: I checked the textfile I was saving and it was still trying to save, its size was 4.7gb when i stopped it.

Comment: Your problem seems related to different lenghts of the arrays firstname, lastname, etc.... Could you put a breakpoint before the start of the loop and report the values of itemcount, firstname.Length, lastname.Length etc....

Comment: each one has a value of 1, except for application date which has 5/04/2011

Comment: Arrays are indexed starting from 0, not 1.

Comment: @Hans Passant thanks for your comment, but I am not quite sure I know what that means or how it could help me, I am very new to vb so sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: I seriously doubt you'll get a straight answer, your question and comments are too vague and inconsistent.  Educate yourself by reading books about vb.net programming.  And learn how to use the debugger.  Not things we can help you with.

Comment: thanks for your honesty, i am doing the best i can with my limited knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

You need to [Set a break point](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/15d1wtaf.aspx) on the line `For loops = 1 To itemcount - 1`

Then press the F8 key and inspect the value of `itemcount` as your code executes. Use this article about [debugging in vb.net](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa290042%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to help you.

From the comments it sounds as though the value of `itemcount` is incorrect in some way.